# Error: Timeout response from the server in Stimulsoft ASP MVC 5

Tags: c#, stimulsoft

I have built an MRT file (Hesab.mrt)  and I use a parameter in a query that controls the numerous number of results to be returned.
 Now everything works great ,untill I enter a big number of results to be returned.
Then I get a "Error: Timeout response from the server." error.

```
    StiReport sr = new StiReport();
    sr.Load(Server.MapPath(@"~/Content/Reports/Hesab.mrt"));            
    sr.RegBusinessObject("Details", "Details", reportList ); 
    sr.Render();         
    return Stimulsoft.Report.Mvc.StiMvcViewer.GetReportSnapshotResult(this.HttpContext, sr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set a **ClientRequestTimeout** option for **MvcViewer** component, the value is set in seconds. The default is **20** seconds.

```
@Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcViewer(
    "Reports",
    new StiMvcViewerOptions() {
        Controller = "Reports",
        ActionGetReportSnapshot = "GetReportSnapshot",
        ActionViewerEvent = "ViewerEvent",
        ActionExportReport = "ExportReport",
        ActionPrintReport = "PrintReport",       
        ClientRequestTimeout = 12345, // <---------------
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In 2018.1.6.0 version this code worked for me.

```
@Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcDesigner( 
     new StiMvcDesignerOptions() {    
         Server = new StiMvcViewerOptions.ServerOptions()   
         {    
             RequestTimeout = 30    
         }    
     }
)
```